# Library issues with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, libraries

I'm trying to build a project with Visual Studio and I get the following two errors:

`C:\secrets\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2545,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "00020813-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 1.9. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
C:\secrets\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2545,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "VBIDE". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.`

I understand this means that two libraries are missing, and that one of them is called VBIDE, but I do not know what the other library is, nor do I know how to add the libraries.

Comment: Try registering the COM component using regsvr32

Comment: How do I do that exactly? I'm sorry if this seems like a stupid question. Do you have a tutorial or something you could link to?

Comment: It is always good to ask , I think this is good reference https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages

Answer (score 2):

On Solution Explorer, Click Show all Files, Click References, Select VBIDE, RightClick it and Remove it.

Comment: I removed both the libraries that are missing and now the error messages are `C:\bleh: warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "00020813-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 1.9. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))` and

`C:\Users\bleh: error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: This worked for me, I was wondering why VBIDE appeared. Anyone have a further explanation?